# Prove the inverse trignometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

Can anybody help me in proving

$$\arccos \frac {\cos x + \cos y} {1 + \cos x \cos y} = 2 \arctan \left( \tan \frac x 2 \tan \frac y 2 \right) ?$$

I am not getting any start.

Comment: Hint: try using $\cos x =\frac{1-\tan^2 (x/2)}{1+\tan^2(x/2)}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

If $\tan^{-1}u=A\implies\tan A=u$

$\cos(2\tan^{-1}u)=\cos2A=\dfrac{1-\tan^2A}{1+\tan^2A}=?$

But keep in mind : [Principal Values of Inverse Trigonometric Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values)

$$2\tan^{-1}u=\cos^{-1}\dfrac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}\text{ if }0\le2\tan^{-1}u\le\pi\iff u\ge0$$
Else i.e. for $u<0,$  $$2\tan^{-1}u=-\cos^{-1}\dfrac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}$$

Comment: But how is this used in question

Comment: @user123733, Here $$u=\tan\dfrac x2\tan\dfrac y2$$

Comment: And how to convert u in terms of cos

Comment: @user123733, $$u^2=\tan^2\dfrac x2\tan^2\dfrac y2=\dfrac{(1-\cos x)(1-\cos y)}{(1+\cos x)(1+\cos y)}$$