# Proof of trignometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

We have to prove the below equation 
 [image]

I try to convert the RHS term into arctan to equate , but I got stuck .

Can anybody help me .

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2066883/prove-the-inverse-trignometric-equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**:(using @lab's comment)

If $\arctan \alpha=A\implies\tan A=\alpha$

$\cos(2\arctan \alpha)=\cos2A=\dfrac{1-\tan^2A}{1+\tan^2A}=?$

In general, $$2\arctan x=\arccos\dfrac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\text{ if }0\le2\arctan x\le\pi\iff x\ge0$$

Substituting for $\alpha = \sqrt{\frac{a-b}{a+b}} \tan \frac{x}{2}$ and doing simple trigonometric identities gives us the answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Here's a pretty helpful hint:**

First, we need to ask ourselves what is the definition of $\tan^{-1}(x)$? Think of a right triangle and SOH-CAH-TOA. I can rewrite ${\tan^{-1}x}$  as $\tan^{-1}{x\over 1}$. Therefore, for some angle $\theta$ we have $\tan\theta = {x\over1}$ Hence, tangent is "opposite over "adjacent", so we have opposite is $x$, adjacent is $1$, and the hypotenuse of our right triangle is $\sqrt{x^2+1}$ by the Pythagorean Theorem.

Now, using this same logic we can write our opposite and adjacent and find the inverse cosine using the same argument, which completes the proof. Here's what's left to you (to decide): What is our opposite and our adjacent? Then what is $\tan{x\over2}$ equal to? Perform some simplification and the result falls out nicely.